# Moving one word to left or right on Mac (in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, macos

We all love our keyboard shortcuts and on a Windows machine two of my most commonly used combos are Ctrl + left/right or Ctrl-Shift + left/right. I find these speed my development quite a bit.

Now on a Mac you can Cmd + left/right which grabs the whole line. And in some apps Option + left/right will navigate a word at a time. I find in Eclipse though that there is not combo to navigate or highlight a word at a time. The option-key combo behaves in a way that is frustrating and makes me want to punch it in the face. Anyone know of features or tricks I might've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mac Keys for Eclipse](http://www.martinkahr.com/2006/02/13/mac-keys-for-eclipse/)